# Multiple loaders in same activity

Tags: java, android

I have two custom built loaders inherited from `AsyncTaskLoader` which I would like to use in my activity. Each of them returns result of different type.
To use my activity for a callback I must implement two interfaces:

```
implements LoaderCallbacks<GetSyncListDataResult>, LoaderCallbacks<ErrorResult>
```

However, trying to implement required methods in the same class I end up with
duplicate method error and erasure(???) error:

```
// Methods for the first loader
public Loader<GetSyncListDataResult> onCreateLoader(int ID, Bundle bundle) ...
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<GetSyncListDataResult> loader) ...
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<GetSyncListDataResult> loader, GetSyncListDataResult result) ...

// Methods for the second loader
public Loader<ErrorResult> onCreateLoader(int ID, Bundle bundle) ...
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ErrorResult> loader) ...
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ErrorResult> loader, ErrorResult result) ...
```

Obviously, the methods are clashing and I need an easy way how to resolve this.
What would be the proper way of resolving this?

Comment: Don't implement the loaders. You can only implement a single loader. Instead, you should declare your LoaderCallbacks as variables.. Ex. LoaderCallbacks<GetSyncListDataResult> syncListCallbacks = new LoaderCallbacks<GetSyncListDataResult>() { ...methods here };

Comment: OK, so it would be best to have an inner anonymous class instance in variable?

Comment: Yes. Then start your loader as getLoaderManager().initLoader(loaderId, bundle, syncListCallbacks);

Comment: OK, you can write this as an answer if you wish and I will accept.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The correct answer is as per @dymmeh's comment, i.e. not for the `Activity` to implement two `LoaderCallbacks` interfaces but for the activity to *contain* two `LoaderCallbacks` implementations. By way of example: initialise your `LoaderCallbacks` fields in your activity...

```
private LoaderCallbacks<GetSyncListDataResult> dataResultLoaderListener
  = new LoaderCallbacks<GetSyncListDataResult>() { ...methods here... };

private LoaderCallbacks<ErrorResult> errorResultLoaderListener
  = new LoaderCallbacks<ErrorResult>() { ...methods here... };
```

... and declare your loader ids...

```
private static final int DATA_RESULT_LOADER_ID = 1;
private static final int ERROR_RESULT_LOADER_ID = 2;
```

... and then initialise your loaders...

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(DATA_RESULT_LOADER_ID, dataResultBundle, dataResultLoaderListener);
getLoaderManager().initLoader(ERROR_RESULT_LOADER_ID, errorResultBundle, errorResultLoaderListener);
```

... Done!

Comment: I have one question. 

The purpose of `Activity` implementing `LoaderCallbacks` and passing `this` in place of dataResultLoaderListener is to ensure that `LoaderManager` acts as communication channel between `Activity` and `Loader` via `LoaderCallbacks`. 

How is that communication channel  being created here as `Activity` isn't implementing `LoaderCallbacks` but rather creating anonymous inner classes?

Comment: @AnV `LoaderCallbacks` itself are the communication channel between the activity and the loader. So anonymous inner classes are fine.

Answer (score 7):

```
class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks {
// you still implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks but without add <returnType> 
//and you have to cast the data into your needed data type in onLoadFinished()

    Private int loader1 = 1;
    private int loader2 =2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(REVIEW_LOADER, null, this);
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(REVIEW_LOADER, null, this);
}
    @Override
    public Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        if (id == loader1 ) {

            //YourLoaderClass1 is you loaderClass where you implement onStartLoading and loadingInBackground() 
            return new YourLoaderClass1();  
        } else if (id == loader2 ) {

            return new YourLoaderClass2();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader loader, Object data) {
        int id = loader.getId();// find which loader you called
        if (id == loader1 ) {

            yourMethod1((List< >) data); // eg. cast data to List<String>
        } else if (id == loader2 ) {
            yourMethod1((String) data); // eg. cast data to String
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader loader) {
        int id = loader.getId();
        if (id == loader1 ) {

        } else if (id == loader2 ) {

        }
    }
}
```

My [Github example](https://github.com/lixw1021/Movies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/xianwei/movies/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Could you provide a bit more explanation with your answer? Code only is rarely as helpful as code + explanation to people who come across this.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and I just add some explanation and hope it helps

Comment: Both task will be executed in series or parallel?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's simpler if you implement `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<T>`  on your Activity class, and using specific loaders ids, manipulate with result.
This way, your code is more readable and functional (because there is no more duplication of interface implementations of inner loader callbacks).

For example :

```
    public class JobListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<NetworkResult> {

        public static final  int    SUBMIT_RISK_ASSESSMENT_LOADER = 546;
        public static final  int    LOAD_RISK_ASSESSMENT_LOADER   = 1546;

        public Loader<NetworkResult> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
            if (id == SUBMIT_RISK_ASSESSMENT_LOADER) {
                return new NetworkLoader( this, args.getString( NetworkLoader.URL_EXTRA ), NetworkLoader.POST, args.getString( BODY ), false ));
            } else if (id == LOAD_RISK_ASSESSMENT_LOADER) {
                return new NetworkLoader( this, args.getString( NetworkLoader.URL_EXTRA ), NetworkLoader.GET, null, false ) );
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<NetworkResult> loader, NetworkResult data) {
            if (data == null) {
                return;
            }

            Crashlytics.log( Log.INFO, TAG, "onLoadFinished with data [" + data + "]" );

            if (loader.getId() == SUBMIT_RISK_ASSESSMENT_LOADER) {
                    doSemethingElse(data);
            } else if (loader.getId() == LOAD_RISK_ASSESSMENT_LOADER) {
                    doSemethingElse(data);
            }
            LoaderManager.getInstance( this ).destroyLoader( loader.getId() );
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't necessary. Implement LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks. Then, each time you initialize a loader, give it a unique ID. In the callbacks, you can detect the ID of the loader that caused the callback and take the appropriate action.

that is

```
class MyLoader extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<GetSyncDataResult> {
...
private static final int LOADER1 = 1;
private static final int LOADER2 = 2;
...
getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER1, null, this);
...
getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER2, null, this);
...

public Loader<GetSyncDataResult> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {

    switch (loaderId) {

    case LOADER1: ...
    case LOADER2: ...
}
...
```

and so forth.

Comment: This answer is not correct as the return type of the two loaders (as specified in the question) is different.

Comment: @AdilHussain what if two loaders are custom loaders ??

Comment: Apologies Amey but I do not understand your question nor see how it is related to the original question in this thread. This thread is about the `LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks` interface and how to setup an activity to listen to 2+ loaders that have different return types.